# Cannot add foreign key through JPA Spring boot by MyISAM

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

im learning JPA Spring boot and create relationship between many table in MySQL through JPA by annotation
@ManyToMany and @OneToMany. But when i launch MySQL to check foreign key i saw that not.

Note: foreign keys can only be defined for certain storage engines (like InnoDB). The server accepts foreign key definitions for other storage engines but silently ignores them. Switch your table engine to  one that supports foreign keys to allow adjustments here.

Please help me to fix this !!! Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect